# How to expect a function to be called in a specific frequency by using Google Test (Mock)?

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

I have a function that is configured to be called in a certain frequency (let's say every second). I need to implement a test that checks whether the function meets this requirement.

I was hoping to have any qualifier like .Frequency(, ) but I could not find it. So I would have:

```
EXPECT_CALL(my_obj, obj_function()).Frequency(900, 1100);
```

How can I validate this requirement by using Google Test?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684208/how-can-i-test-a-call-is-made-after-a-delay-in-google-test-using-a-mocking-frame), but it is similar. I think you can do something like:

```
StartTimer()
EXPECT_CALL(my_obj, obj_function());
EndTimer();
ASSERT_TRUE(elapsedTime() >= 0.9);
ASSERT_TRUE(elapsedTime() <= 1.1);
```

Either in a loop, or repeated the suitable amount of time - presumably you don't want to run this for hours, but a handful of calls...